# python get time in minutes

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.4

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 31)
end = datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 1)
print end-start
>>1 day, 0:00:00//output
```

How to get the output in minutes

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 31)
end = datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 1)
diff = end-start
print (diff.days * 1440) + (diff.seconds / 60)
>> 1440.0
```

(I'm assuming you don't need microsecond resolution here - but if you do, just add in a third term using `diff.microseconds` with the proper divisor to convert to minutes.)

and after the release of the [python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html) you can use the method [total_seconds](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds)

```
print (diff.total_seconds() / 60)
```